# How can I create multiple shared libraries with maven nar plugin?

Tags: c, maven, shared-libraries, maven-nar-plugin

How can I create multiple shared libraries with maven nar plugin? Here is a snippet from my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
    <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>compile-C-shared-lib</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>nar-compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>generate_c_header_from_java</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>nar-javah</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
      <libraries>
        <library>
        </library>
      </libraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can create a shared library with this pom. But I want to build two libraries. From pack of source files. How can I do this?